# Start another program from python subprocess module at system startup in ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, boot, pika

I have a problem starting another process from python at system startup,
but not when running from terminal.

My code :

```
import pika
import time
import sys
import logging
import json
import os
import config
import subprocess as sp
from pika.exceptions import AMQPConnectionError, ConnectionClosed

logging.basicConfig(filename='/opt/myapp/logs/pika.log', format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')


global con 

try:
    con = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=config.HOST_IP))
    print "Connected to RabbitMQ Server..."
    logging.info('Connected to RabbitMQ Server')    
except AMQPConnectionError:
    sys.exit(0)


ch = con.channel()

ch.queue_declare(queue='msgs', durable=True)

def on_recieve(ch, method, properties, body):
    print body
    data = json.loads(body)
    res_ip_raw = data['laptop_ip']
    res_ip_decoded = res_ip_raw.replace("\r\n", "")

    if res_ip_decoded == config.LAPTOP_IP:
    logging.info(body)
        # **Unable to lauch this**
    child=sp.Popen("/usr/bin/firefox", shell=True)

    logging.info('Launching firefox with pid '+str(child.pid) )
        time.sleep( body.count('.'))
        ch.basic_ack( delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)


ch.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
ch.basic_consume(on_recieve, queue='msgs')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        ch.start_consuming()
    except (ConnectionClosed, KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        sys.exit(0)
```

this is my startup script

start_up.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
nohup /usr/bin/python /opt/myapp/main.py &
```

The main.py works fine and firefox launches 
when i run this from terminal as
./main.py or as /etc/init.d/start_up.sh

Any help ?

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you placed `start_up.sh` on `/etc/init.d/` and made it executable?

Comment: Maybe Firefox cannot start without a `$DISPLAY` variable set?  I.e., it's a GUI application that can't run without a GUI.

Comment: @pynovice Yes i have done it.

Comment: @Majenko But it runs fine from terminal, i have this issue only at rsystem boot

Comment: Yes, but a terminal is running in a GUI - at system boot there is no GUI.

Comment: @Majenko, but if so , then how to solve this. But if i make another script like #!/bin/sh /usr/bin/firefox and put this at boot this works fine

Comment: One question: at what point in the boot sequence are you executing these scripts?

Comment: @Majenko, i'm sorry you are right ? GUI does not get load. on boot. there was a little confusion . But the question remains that i'm triggering firefox only if i get message from rabbitmq . on boot main.py is running and successfully connected to rabbitmqserver

Comment: I think you want to be loading your script not as part of the boot sequence, but as part of the login sequence - i.e., add it to the Startup Applications, not to the rc system.  That way the script is run as you inside your desktop session, not as root in a non-desktop environment.